# AngularFire2 Doesn't sign user out with

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I'm trying to implement Firebase auth in my Ionic 4 app with the AngularFire2 Library. I set up the correct imports so that I can access other AngularFireAuth properties but I can't seem to succesfully execute a sign out. All my firebase auth stuff currently happens on a page named home.

I've tried removing the promise but that doesn't seem to do anything.

This is the view pre-sign in
[image: pre-sign in]

this is the view post-sign in
[image]

Here's my typescript file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      location.reload();
    });
  }
}
```

Here's my HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="ion-padding">
    The world is your oyster.
    <p>If you get lost, the <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">docs</a> will be your guide.</p>
  </div>
<firebase-ui></firebase-ui> <!-- EDIT: this is what firebaseui-angular uses to display the login UI -->
  <h1 *ngIf="afAuth.auth.currentUser">Welcome {{afAuth.auth.currentUser.displayName}}</h1>
  <ion-button *ngIf="afAuth.auth.currentUser" (click)="signOut">Sign Out</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

I expected the Sign Out button to update the page and bring the login window back and remove the Welcome Mike text and remove the sign out button. Instead the sign out button didn't do anything.

Comment: what is this `<firebase-ui></firebase-ui>`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Those tags are for firebaseui-angular to display the login ui (they're on NPM). That part wasn't really an issue since the login ui always displayed flawlessly and auto hides after sign in.

Comment: are u using ionic 3?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I'm using Ionic 4

Comment: okay did my answer work

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      location.reload();
    });
  }
```

into this (ionic 3):

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.navCtrl.pop();
    });
  }
```

If you are using ionic 4, then use the following:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.navCtrl.back();
    });
  }
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what I wrote.. but i gave you two cases one for ionic 3 and one for ionic 4, its one constructor...

Comment: It didn't work as you said. I tried to make some sense of it myself. I presumed you meant this. It didn't make sense to have two constructors or have a constructor inside the signOut class so I thought this would work but it didn't.: pastebin.com/fYqcaGiX Does it have anything to do with the fact that I just navigate to that page with /home at the end (my homepage in app-routing is something else.) @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It was a pretty trivial mistake. 
I accidentally didn't call the function correctly from the HTML side

This:

```
<ion-button *ngIf="afAuth.auth.currentUser" (click)="signOut">Sign Out</ion-button>
```

Should be this:

```
<ion-button *ngIf="afAuth.auth.currentUser" (click)="signOut();">Sign Out</ion-button>
```

In any case thanks for the effort (it was probably smart to use navCtrl for the "refresh" anyway)